# Kummer solution to second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I need to solve a second order linear ODE with non-constant coefficients of the form

$$
\frac{d^2Z}{dt^2}+(a+be^{-ct})\frac{dZ}{dt}+dZ=0
$$

where $a,b,c,f$ are positive real constants.

Mathematica provides me with this solution

$$
i^{(a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4 d})/c}\, b^{(a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4 d})/2 c}\,
   c^{-(a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4 d})/2 c} \,{e^{-c t}}^{(
  a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4 d})/2 c}\, C[1]\, \text{Hypergeometric1F1}\left[\frac{a}{2c} - \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - 4 d}}{2c}, 1 - \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - 4 d}}{c}, \frac{be^{-ct}}{c}\right] +\\ 
i^{(a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4 d})/c}\, b^{(a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4 d})/2 c}\,
   c^{-(a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4 d})/2 c} \,{e^{-c t}}^{(
  a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4 d})/2 c}\, C[2]\, \text{Hypergeometric1F1}\left[\frac{a}{2c} + \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - 4 d}}{2c}, 1 + \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - 4 d}}{c}, \frac{be^{-ct}}{c}\right]
$$

but I don't quite get how to derive such an expression. Any hint?

Comment: Let $x = (b/c) e^{- c t}$ and then transform the equation for $Z(t)$ into one for $Z(x)$. Once completed compare the differential equation to that of the confluent hypergeometric equation.

Comment: I had already tried that, but if I'm not mistaken I get
$$
c^2 x^2 \frac{d^2 Z^2}{dx^2}=cx(a-c+cx)\frac{dZ}{dx}-dZ
$$
(sorry for the confusion with the constant $d$). Again, if the expression above is correct, and even though I know Kummer equation is
$$
z \frac{d^2 w^2}{dz^2}+(b-z)\frac{dw}{dz}-aw=0
$$
I can't link the two

Comment: In your $Z(x)$ equation try another change of the form $Z(x) = x^{\alpha} \, F(x)$. There will be an quadratic to solve to find $\alpha$ which appears to have the solution $(a - \sqrt{a^2 - a d})/(2c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 
$$y'' + (a + b e^{-ct}) \, y' + d \, y = 0$$
let $c x = b \, e^{-c t}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{b}{c} \, e^{-c t} \\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= - c x \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= - c x \, \frac{dy}{dx} = - c x y' \\
\frac{d^{2} y}{d x^{2}} &= c^{2} \, x \, \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \, \frac{dy}{dx} \right) = c^{2} \, (x^2 y'' + x y' )
\end{align}
and 
$$x^2 \, y'' + x \left(1 - \frac{a}{c} - x \right) \, y' + \frac{d}{c^{2}} \, y = 0.$$
Let $y = x^{\alpha} \, f$ to obtain
\begin{align}
y &= x^{\alpha} \, f \\
y' &= x^{\alpha} \, \left(f' + \frac{\alpha}{x} \, f \right) \\
y'' &= x^{\alpha} \, \left( f'' + \frac{2 \alpha}{x} \, f' + \frac{\alpha(\alpha -1)}{x^2} \, y \right)
\end{align}
and
$$x f'' + \left( 1 - \frac{a}{c} + 2 \alpha - x \right) \, f' + \left(\frac{c^{2} \alpha^{2} - a c \alpha + d}{c^{2} \, x} - \alpha \right) y = 0.$$

Now let $c^{2} \alpha^{2} - a c \alpha + d = 0$, $p = 1 - (a/c) + 2 \alpha$, such that the last equation becomes
$$x f'' + (p - x) f' - \alpha f = 0$$
and has solution
$$f(x) = A_{0} \, {}_{1}F_{1}(\alpha; p; x).$$
Backward sunstitutions lead to
$$y(x) = A_{0} \, \left( \frac{b}{c} \, e^{- c t} \right)^{\alpha} \, {}_{1}F_{1}\left(\alpha; 1 - \frac{a}{c} + 2 \alpha; \frac{b}{c} \, e^{-c t} \right).$$

Note that $c^{2} \alpha^{2} - a c \alpha + d = 0$ has solutions 
$$\alpha = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4d}}{2 c}$$
which assist in the two possible solutions. With initial conditions, or asymptotic forms, the solution can further be reduced.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to apply both the substitutions you suggested but got lost somewhere in the process

Comment: Actually, doesn't the confluent equation for $f$ have solution

$$
A_0 {}_{1}F_1(\alpha,p,x)+A_1 U(\alpha,p,x)
$$

?

Comment: @Muriel There are two solutions to the confluent hypergeometric differential equation, without transformations, but the acceptable solutions depend on the initial conditions, or asymptotic conditions. In the solution provided the primary solution to ${}_{1}F_{1}$ is provided with two possible forms of $\alpha$. In the general sense this is usually the accepted form to most solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Making

$$
\xi = a+b e^{-ct}\Rightarrow \dot \xi = -c(\xi-a)
$$

Now changing variables

$$
\ddot Z + (a+b e^{-ct})\dot Z + d Z \equiv c^2\ddot Z(t-a)^2+c(c-1)\dot Z (t-a)+dZ = 0
$$

This last equation has an easy solution as

$$
Z(\xi) = C_1 (a-\xi)^{-\frac{\left(-\frac{\sqrt{1-4 d}}{\sqrt{d}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\right) \sqrt{d}}{2 c}}+C_2 (a-\xi)^{-\frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-4
   d}}{\sqrt{d}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\right) \sqrt{d}}{2 c}}
$$