# Kummer transformation for a homogenous second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to transform the following differential equation
$$\frac{\sigma^2}{2}x^2y''+(1-rx)y'-\lambda y=0$$
Into a Kummer differential equation, so something of the form:
$$
xf''(x)+(b-z)f'(x)-af(x)=0.
$$
From reading some other posts I tried using $y=x^af(x)$, but it didn't work, or at least I couldn't get it to work.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

**Edit**. I'm reffering to this post [Kummer solution to second order ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745254/kummer-solution-to-second-order-ode) : what I can't get is to have $xf''$ without having a $\frac{1}{x}f'(x)$ term

Comment: Try $y=x^af(x^b)$.

Comment: I'm trying it rn although but doesn't it cause issues later on with the fact that your function is evaluated at $x^b$, or am I missing somethin?

Comment: What kind of issues?

Comment: Rather as in wouldn't I need to make another change of variables later on to get rid of the inner $x^b$?

Comment: I see your point. You can do it in two steps, as $y(x)= f(z)$, where $z=ax^b$, followed by $f(z)=z^cg(z)$, or in a single step, as $y(x)=z^cg(z)$, where $z=ax^b$. The final result is the same, but the second alternative is more prone to errors.

Comment: Mh, yeah I'm not getting it to work, probably messing something up lol